# App styling in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I cannot seem to find the right solution to increase and decrease the text size of the whole android app project.I want to give user an option so the user can change the font size of the whole app. I tried extend my Base-activity to Text-view but didn't do the trick i hope anyone here can help me.

Comment: you want to increase size of android studio text size?

Comment: use theme, to apply styling in all UI in project.

Comment: Actually i want to give user an option to change the font size of an app

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to update `textSize` of TextViews from Design tab in 
.xml files that you can find at `res > layout` like `activity_main.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change size for whole app, Try custom themes and set it dynamically.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>
 <style name="AppTheme3" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        </style>
```

Create separate themes for different sizes, and use this class for setting it.

```
public class themeUtils
{
    public static int cTheme;
    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme)
    {
        cTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION));

    }

    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity)
    {
        try
        {
            activity.setTheme(cTheme);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme); //default
        }

    }

}
```

In your activity, call this method before super.oncreate() method,

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        themeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...}
```

Finally change theme in your code where ever you want,

```
  themeUtils.changeToTheme(this, themeselected);//your theme name
```

Comment: Actually i want to give user an option to change the font size of an app

Comment: @MuhammadZuhair create separate theme as I edited my answer, And when the user chooses size then call the method with that theme name

Comment: And one more thing, initially ctheme value is not set, Hence it will throw exception. So use try block